# SMTP Python Connection unexpectedly closed

Tags: python, email, smtplib

Hello to all on my question page.

So what happened was I wanted to create a program to email myself automatically with a spam email I made at once every hour just to learn some cool python libraries, but when I run the program, it gives me an error. The error is right below my code. I have blocked the password because it is private and yeah. Before you guys say it is because the password is wrong, it is not because if it were, it would say "Authentication failed"

My Code:

```
#imports
import smtplib

port = 465

smtp_server = "mail.gmx.com"
email = "kbodfkghset232gvja23@gmx.us"
password = "****************"
target = "gerik700@gmail.com"
message = """
Subject: Test

This is a test message
"""

#login to server to send email
server = smtplib.SMTP(host=smtp_server, port=port)
try:
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    server.set_debuglevel(1)
    server.ehlo()
    #sending message
    server.sendmail(email, target, message)


except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    server.quit()
```

My Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Email_Program.py", line 17, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP(host=smtp_server, port=port)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 338, in connect
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 394, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

According to https://support.gmx.com/pop-imap/imap/windowsmailapp.html, clients sending outgoing mail through mail.gmx.com should connect on port 587 and use `starttls`.  So, first try changing your script to connect on port 587 instead of port 465.  Also, you'll need to send the `ehlo` command before the `starttls` command, then again after the `starttls` command.  The following should work:

```
import smtplib

to='to@to.com'
fromname='sender'
fromemail='from@from.com'
subject='this is the subject'
body='this is the message body'

message=''
message+= "To: " + to + "\n"
message+= "From: \"" + fromname + "\" <" + fromemail + ">\n"
message+= "Subject: " + subject + "\n"
message+= "\n"
message+= body

mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('mail.gmx.com',587)
mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.starttls()
mailserver.ehlo()  #again
mailserver.login('username', 'password')
mailserver.sendmail(fromemail, to, message)
mailserver.quit()
```

Comment: I tried the above code, it is not working. Throwing SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'Authentication credentials invalid') could you help

Comment: try smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)